# Read map object stored as string from file

Tags: java, scala, scala-collections

I saved my map without doing any pre-processing to a file. So I have a file where I have my map *object* as:

```
Map(abcd -> List(1,2,3), efgh -> List(78,46))
```

So when I read it, its read as a string.

**How do I convert this to a map object?**

Comment: You would need to do a very complex parsing... or maybe invoke the **Scala** interpreter in runtime but that would also be too complex. Why not. instead of storing the string representation of your map you store the data in a representation that is easier to parse, maybe **JSON** or **XML** or you can create your own format for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by others, it's inefficient to store Map data as a String.  Anyway, assuming the Map element types are known in advance (in this case `Map[String, List[Int]]`), you could use a Regex pattern to pair up all `string -> List(...)`, followed by splitting and converting the `List` content to integers:

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

val s = "Map(abcd -> List(1,2,3), efgh -> List(78,46))"

val pattern = """(\w+)\s*->\s*List\(([^\)]*)\)""".r

pattern.findAllMatchIn(s).flatMap(_.subgroups).grouped(2).
  collect{ case Seq(k, v) =>
    val ls = v.split("""\s*,\s*""").map(x => Try(x.toInt) match {
      case Success(i) => i
      case Failure(_) => Int.MinValue  // Or any other default integer
    })
    (k, ls.toList)
  }.
  toMap
// res1: Map[String, List[Int]] = Map("abcd" -> List(1, 2, 3), "efgh" -> List(78, 46))
```